# PHP JSON - How to select the entries which following when meet a specific condition

Tags: php, json, preprocessor

I am dummy in PHP and I am really struggling to understand how to archive this that I am going to describe.

The goal is to make a sub-selection of the entries that following, after a condition: **type == STATUS AND VALUE == 40** that is the blocks of the IDs (3, 8, 28, 33)

This json is the response from an SQL query.

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 23,
            "DATETIME": "1612515739000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "DATETIME": "1612515745000",
            "VALUE": "40",
            "type": "STATUS",
            "key": "0_203_status",
            "unit": "",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "DATETIME": "1612515754000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 8,
            "DATETIME": "1612515760000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 14,
            "DATETIME": "1612515775000",
            "VALUE": "20",
            "type": "STATUS",
            "key": "0_203_status",
            "unit": "",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 13,
            "DATETIME": "1612515775000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 18,
            "DATETIME": "1612515790000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 25,
            "DATETIME": "1612515805000",
            "VALUE": "40",
            "type": "STATUS",
            "key": "0_203_status",
            "unit": "",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 28,
            "DATETIME": "1612515813000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 33,
            "DATETIME": "1612515820000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected respond

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "DATETIME": "1612515754000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
       {
            "ID": 8,
            "DATETIME": "1612515760000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 28,
            "DATETIME": "1612515813000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 33,
            "DATETIME": "1612515820000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        }

    ]
}
```

I have attached an image for the selection logic.
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far (if anything)? While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort towards reaching the solution. Also, it is unclear what your exact issue is. Do you not know how to extract data from JSON? Do you not know how to filter the array once the data is extracted? Also, why isn't this filtering done in the database query itself?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. As you suggested, I will try to extract data from json or to filter those. Filtering from DB is not possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This script will solve your problem

```php
<?php

$json = '{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": 23,
            "DATETIME": "1612515739000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "DATETIME": "1612515745000",
            "VALUE": "40",
            "type": "STATUS",
            "key": "0_203_status",
            "unit": "",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "DATETIME": "1612515754000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 8,
            "DATETIME": "1612515760000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 14,
            "DATETIME": "1612515775000",
            "VALUE": "20",
            "type": "STATUS",
            "key": "0_203_status",
            "unit": "",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 13,
            "DATETIME": "1612515775000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 18,
            "DATETIME": "1612515790000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 25,
            "DATETIME": "1612515805000",
            "VALUE": "40",
            "type": "STATUS",
            "key": "0_203_status",
            "unit": "",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 28,
            "DATETIME": "1612515813000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        },
        {
            "ID": 33,
            "DATETIME": "1612515820000",
            "VALUE": "327.67",
            "type": "AVGKMKWH",
            "key": "0_202_avgkmKwh",
            "unit": "Km/Kwh",
            "policy": "PERIODIC",
            "device_id": "1245454545454",
            "voucher_id": "12451"
        }
    ]
}';

function checkCondition($element) {
    $conditions = [
        "VALUE" => "40",
        "type"  => "STATUS"
    ];

    foreach ($conditions as $conditionKey => $conditionValue) {
        if (isset($element[$conditionKey]) && $element[$conditionKey] != $conditionValue) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

$dataInArray = json_decode($json, true);
$array = $dataInArray["data"];
print_r(array_filter($array, "checkCondition"));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [DATETIME] => 1612515745000
            [VALUE] => 40
            [type] => STATUS
            [key] => 0_203_status
            [unit] => 
            [policy] => PERIODIC
            [device_id] => 1245454545454
            [voucher_id] => 12451
        )
    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 25
            [DATETIME] => 1612515805000
            [VALUE] => 40
            [type] => STATUS
            [key] => 0_203_status
            [unit] => 
            [policy] => PERIODIC
            [device_id] => 1245454545454
            [voucher_id] => 12451
        )
)
```

First I use `json_decode` to convert the json to the array, and then use `$conditions` variable to add my condition and finally I use `checkCondition` function and iterate the array and check my condition.